# SUM aggregations rounds each value?

Tags: elasticsearch

My index contains two elements:

```
{
  "pound" : 1.5
}
```

When ES sums the two elements together thanks to the `SUM` aggregation, each `pound` value are rounded to `1` instead of keeping `1.5`. Why?

The result should be `3`, not `2`.

Here's my ES request:

```
POST foo/bar/_search
{
   "aggs": {
      "sumPound": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "pound"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And the response:

```
{
   ...,
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            ...,
            "_source": {
               "pound": 1.5,
            }
         },
         {
            ...,
            "_source": {
               "pound": 1.5,
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "sumPound": {
         "value": 2          <-- 1.5 + 1.5 == 2 ???
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your mapping, is the type of the `pound` field is set to `double` ? It looks like it's an `integer`.

Comment: Actually it was a `long`. Good catch!